# Lawtex - Mudar o print padrão de uma struct

Tags: id, lawtex

Tenho a seguinte struct no meu programa:

```
+<vara>: struct[Vara] {
                name = "Dados da Vara"
                request = "Preencha os dados da vara"
                fields {
                    +[numero] : Integer { 
                        name = "Número"
                        request = "Número"
                        help = "Caso seja a 19ª Vara, preencha \"19\""
                        default = 20
                    },
                    +[tipo]: List("Vara Cível", "Vara Trabalhista"){
                        name = "Tipo"
                        request = "Tipo"
                        atomic = true
                    },
                    +[estado]: String {
                        name = "Estado"
                        request = "Estado"
                    },
                    +[cidade]: String {
                        name = "Cidade"
                        request = "Cidade"
                    }
                }
            },
```

Eu gostaria de adicionar um padrão diferente de `print` para jogar somente `print <vara>` no `operations`, e que ele me imprimisse com esse formato: 
1a VARA CÍVEL DA COMARCA DE SÃO PAULO - SP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o parâmetro `id` da struct, e nesse formato, é só imprimir isso que vai funcionar:
                `id = uppercase([numero] & "ª " & [tipo] & " DA COMARCA DE " & [cidade] & "-" & [estado])`

Comment: Interessante que no parâmetro `id` consigo concatenar text usando tubes e variáveis do mesmo jeito!

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a [resposta do @atGuz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348348/112052): quando você usar uma `struct` com `id` num vetor, basta executar o vetor que as infos serão printadas nos conformes do `id`, dispensando o uso de `foreach`.

```
+|paragrafosComImagensAbaixo| : Vector[ParagrafosComImagensAbaixo] {
                        name = "Impugnações adicionais e as provas correspondentes"
                        request = "Impugnações adicionais e as provas correspondentes"
                        lower = 1
                    }

struct[ParagrafosComImagensAbaixo] {
            id = "O documento juntado é: " & [documentoEmbasarImpugnacaoAdicional] & ", cuja descrição é " & [paragrafo] & "."
            name = "Impugnações adicionais e as provas correspondentes"
            request = "Impugnações adicionais e as provas correspondentes"
            fields {
                +[paragrafo] : Text {
                    name = "Descrição da impugnação adicional"
                    request = "Descreva aqui os fatos ou circunstâncias que se contraponham às alegações e/ou provas da Parte Autora"
                },
                +[documentoEmbasarImpugnacaoAdicional] : Boolean {
                    name = "Documento para embasar impugnação adicional"
                    request = "Existe algum documento ou imagem para embasar a impugnação adicional"
                },
                if ([documentoEmbasarImpugnacaoAdicional]) {
                    +|nomeImagemImpugnacao| : Vector[String] {
                        name = "Nome da imagem"
                        request = "Insira o nome da imagem"
                        lower = 1
                    },
                    +[localizacaoImagemImpugnacao] : List ("Anexo", "Corpo do documento") {
                        name = "Localização da imagem"
                        request = "Deseja que o documento seja apresentado nos anexos ou conste no corpo do documento?"
                        atomic = true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Quando escutado `|paragrafosComImagensAbaixo|`, será printado o seguinte:

> "O documento juntado é: " & [documentoEmbasarImpugnacaoAdicional] & ", cuja descrição é " & [paragrafo] & "."